# How do compare the user input to multiple variable at a time?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying a basic program that replicates the game called mastermind. I have been able to so far get 4 data points, and 4 user inputs as an integer, but I have a problem comparing 4 data points and the 4 user inputs. The goal is the is there are 4 rngs(ranging from 1-9) and the user guesses 4 numbers at a time. The only hint that he is given is that one number is correct. So far I have been able to make an inefficient code that is set to compare 4 variables, ex( a=rng1, b=rng2, c=rng3, d=rng4) and the user input similarly. How do I efficiently compare the user inputs to all of the rngs that have generated.In this instance I want to be able to compare s1 to poop; poop2; poop3; and poop4. I don't want to write another 100 lines of code to do that. Thanks in advance. Code is below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomNumberGenerator{;
private static Scanner in;
public static void main(String[] args){
  Random r = new Random();
  float s;
  in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int poop = (r.nextInt(10-1)+1);
  int poop1 = (r.nextInt(10-1)+1);
  int poop2 = (r.nextInt(10-1)+1);
  int poop3 = (r.nextInt(10-1)+1);
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
{
System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-9");
s = in.nextFloat();
float s1 = in.nextFloat();
float s2 = in.nextFloat();
float s3 = in.nextFloat();

if(poop == s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 == s3) {
    System.out.println("You are correct HeHe XD");
    break;
    }
if(poop > s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop < s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop > s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 > s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 < s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 > s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 < s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 > s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 < s3){
    System.out.println("You have 1 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 != s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 2 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 != s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 2 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 != s3){
    System.out.println("You have 2 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 != s1 && poop2 != s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 2 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 != s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 != s3){
    System.out.println("You have 2 wrong");
}
if(poop == s && poop1 != s1 && poop2 != s2 && poop3 != s3){
    System.out.println("You have 3 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 != s2 && poop3 != s3){
    System.out.println("You have 3 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 != s1 && poop2 == s2 && poop3 != s3){
    System.out.println("You have 3 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 != s1 && poop2 != s2 && poop3 == s3){
    System.out.println("You have 3 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 == s1 && poop2 != s2 && poop3 != s3){
    System.out.println("You have 3 wrong");
}
if(poop != s && poop1 != s1 && poop2 != s2 && poop3 != s3){
    System.out.println("You have 4 wrong");
}

 }

 }
}
```

Comment: is that code working?

Comment: **tip**  avoid comparing `int` with `float`

Comment: @AsteriskNinja yes the code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two ArrayList for storing 4 data points and user inputs. Then comparing using `ArrayList.contains()`. You don't have to write a lot of `if condition`. Refer to my code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      final int totalPoints = 4;
      Random r = new Random();
      in = new Scanner(System.in);

      ArrayList<Integer> poops = new ArrayList<Integer>(totalPoints);
      ArrayList<Integer> userinputs = new ArrayList<Integer>(totalPoints);

      for (int i=0; i<totalPoints; i++) {
          int poop = (r.nextInt(10-1)+1);
          System.out.println("Random datapoints: " + poop);
          poops.add(poop);
      }


      System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-9");
      for (int i=0; i<totalPoints; i++) {
          int s = in.nextInt();
          userinputs.add(s);
      }

      int correct = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
          if (poops.contains(userinputs.get(i))) {
              correct++;
          }
      }

      System.out.println("You have " + correct + "correct numbers");

}
```

Comment: god bless you! it works great, I am a nooby programmer that just started java so using arrays and learning them are a little difficult. Thanks A lot!

Comment: One problem is that it doesn't loop once it says i have 'x' wrong numbers. You have used `for = (i=0; i<4; i++)`  which is what I used to loop the entire code.

Comment: @ArchitSrivastava But keep in mind: having people giving code to you is convenient; but probably not the best way to learn. You learn more when you pick up "keywords" and study those concepts yourself. Reading "written code" will always "teach less" compared to writing code yourself.

Comment: @GhostCat yea I know, I already resolved the problem! Thanks though.

Comment: @Rocherlee I have made a working loop for the program, but for reasons that I don't understand it repeats the statement "You have 'x' correct numbers' after more than 1 turn. It repeats it even if I put numbers that aren't present in the `poop` variable.

Comment: Do you want the program to loop 80 times like you did? You should include your current code here. You can upload it to pastebin and paste the link here.

Answer (score 1):

Put your variables in a `List` then you can check with `contains` if an Element is in the `List`.
Actually you get two numbers as feedback in mastermind, how many are a correct Number and how many are also at the correct place.
Since there are duplicates possible in mastermind, you can make a `copy` of your original `List` and for each correct `guess` `remove` it from the `List`. Otherwise guessing all the same `number` would be correct if the master `contains` that number.

```
int size = 4;
List<Integer> poops = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
    poops.add((r.nextInt(10-1)+1));
}
...
List<Integer> guesses= new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
   guesses.add(in.nextInt());
}
int correctNumberCount = 0;
List<Integer> poopsCopy = new ArrayList<>(poops);
for(Integer guess: guesses){
    if(poopsCopy.contains(guess)){
        correctNumberCount ++;
        //For handling duplicates
        poopsCopy.remove(guess);
    }   
} 
int correctCount = 0;
int counter = 0;
for(Integer guess: guesses){
    if(guess == poops.get(counter)){
        correctCount++;
    }
    counter++; 
}
//Inform the user about correctNumberCount and correctCount
```

Comment: Thanks, It works great, learning arrays were difficult for me since I just started Java. I get some more of it now!

Answer (score 1):

You don't do it with variables named p1, p2, p3, ...

You step back and read about the concepts of arrays!

Then you create two arrays (preferable with **int**; not float!).
The first array carries the 4 values that your program thinks up; and the second array is filled with 4 values coming from the user.

Then you **iterate** both arrays; to figure how many elements in the "user" array are given in the "computer" array. Really: you **never ever** should write code that contains so many if/else statements. Such code is absolutely impossible to read or maintain. Don't do that. Ever.

Alternatively, you can look **Collections**, those are more sophisticated data structures. In your case you can work with List/ArrayList of Integer objects. When you are interested in that stuff; use your favorite search engine and read about it.

Comment: In mastermind you can have duplicate `numbers` (originally Colours) , so a `Set`is not appropriate here.

Comment: @garnulf Ah, right. Long ago that I played that game. In that case he would need a Map where the value would be a counter if one value is used more than once. That would probably blow his mind. Thanks for your input; I removed the set part from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, you only need to get the wrong number of each input combination but not where it is wrong. So, there is no need for you to enumerate all possibilities.

You can try the code below, the `size` is the number indicating how many inputs allowed for user.

I have used `List` to store the numbers. It's a good habit to keep a series of data into container so that you can operate them with `loop` easily and `loop` is one of the strongest power of computer.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomNumberGenerator {

    private static Scanner in;

    private static List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static private final int size = 4;

    static int correctNumber = 0;

    public static void check(List<Integer> expected, List<Integer> input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (expected.get(i) == input.get(i)) {
                correctNumber++;
            }
        }

        if (correctNumber == size) {
            System.out.println("You are correct HeHe XD");
            return;
        } else {
            int wrongNumber = size - correctNumber;
            System.out.println("You have " + wrongNumber + " wrong");
            correctNumber = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = size;
        while(count > 0){
            expected.add((r.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1));
            count--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers from 1-9");
            count = size;
            while(count > 0){
                input.add(in.nextInt());
                count--;
            }
            check(expected, input);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

how about:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomNumberGenerator{;
private static Scanner in;
public static void main(String[] args){
  Random r = new Random();
  float s;
  in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int[] poops = new int[4];
  for(int i=0;i<poops.length;i++){
      poops[i]=r.nextInt(10-1)+1;
  }

float[] s = new float[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-9");
    int error =0;
    for(int j=0;j<poops.length;j++){
         if(poop[j] != in.nextFloat()){
             error++;
         }
     }
     if(result == 0){
         System.out.println("You are correct HeHe XD");
         break;
     }else{
         System.out.println("You have "+error+" wrong");
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: You check for `result` but your variable is `error`, so this doesn't compile. Also comparing `int` with `float`leads to trouble.